# Oracle licencia y Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oracle, licencias

Quiero iniciar un proyecto en Android Studio, estoy desarrollándolo en kotline, recordé que el JDK cambiaron las licencias y ahora es de pago, ¿tengo que pagar si quiero volver mi app comercial?.

Comment: La licencia comercial aplica para despliegues en ambientes productivos. Para desarrollo no tienes que pagar. Igual, lo recomendable es que, para efectos de compatibilidad y de no lidiar con vericuetos legales, compiles contra una compilación del JDK open source (puedes ir a adoptopenjdk y bajar el instalador)

Comment: Toma en cuenta la opción que te plantea @Alfabravo entre paréntesis. Revisa este blog: [OpenJ9 una nueva alternativa para Oracle JDK](https://medium.com/karibu-blog/openj9-una-nueva-alternativa-para-la-jdk-de-oracle-e71d8f36a587) seguro te orientas adecuadamente...

Comment: Nicolas, la única versión del JDK por la que hay que pagar licencia en producción es el Oracle JDK (como bien te dice @Alfabravo). Las alternativas que yo uso son: [OpenJDK](http://jdk.java.net/), [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html) y [Zulu OpenJDK](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/)

Comment: Para cerrar los comentarios (que todos son muy pertinentes), recuerda que los fuentes de Java son open-source y puedes encontrar muchas *compilaciones* diferentes, que van a variar en los ajustes, bugs, parches, mejoras específicas que le puedan añadir (ej: Amazon tiene Coretto, que tiene cosas pa que funcione mejor en sus ambientes AWS, etc). Pero OpenJDK es el mismo, siempre. Busca el que te funcione mejor en tu entorno, explora las opciones que te han dado y trata de no usar versiones Oracle a menos que tus clientes estén cubiertos en licencias comerciales y no sea un lío más adelante.